# HttpOnly Chrome extension cookies still unavailable

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I've got a Chrome Extension I am writing to emulate certain gui calls and automate them, everything is working as intended except that I cannot see any contents inside `chrome.cookies`. I can get limited cookie data from `document.cookie` but I need the `chrome.cookies` extension options to emulate the session. Basically by default https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly restricts that access (which is normally fine)

this is what I am trying to get at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies

In order to access `chrome.cookies` I have altered my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Call Builder",
  "description": "This extension auto creates Dialog nodes",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "myPopup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["cookies", "tabs",  "*://*.mydomain.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mydomain.com/*"],
      "js": ["router.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

note the line `"permissions": ["cookies", "tabs",  "*://*.mydomain.com/*"],` I know I've done the right thing with `"cookies"` in `"permissions"` but when I try to access `chrome.cookies` (or any of it's methods) it is empty (`undefined`) what is the reason?

**EDIT**

PLEASE READ MY COMMENT BELOW :-) this issue is a scoping issue and it's not documented nor covered - **TLDR;** while `chrome.tabs` is available in both js spaces `chrome.cookies` isn't and this isn't mentioned in the answer nor the chrome documentation

Comment: See the content scripts documentation: only several chrome API are exposed. Do it in the popup or use an event/background page script.

Comment: so it's popup only?

Comment: Pardon me, what do you mean by that?

Comment: the answer in the `"suggested answer"` isn't actually answering the question. It is a scoping issue, and it's not documented and it's misleading in the the extreme. Basically the answer is that the ` "chrome.cookies"` object is available via `"myPopup.html"` via it's associated JavaScripts, it's *NOT* available in "content_scripts": like router.js in my example.. the reason this is misleading is that the websocket piping object `chrome.tabs` *is* available in both scopes